# Compact representation of tree

Tags: data-structures, tree

I'm trying to represent a tree in a more compact format, with an eye towards embedded systems.

My trees are binary and fairly balanced (max depth ~20, but size ~50K nodes). The algorithm that produces them uses a node structure similar to

```
class Node {
   BinaryFunction BF(Input->Boolean);
   [optional] Node LeftNode;
   [optional] Result LeftResult;
   [optional] Node RightNode;
   [optional] Result RightResult;
}
```

where `Result` takes a few bits and Node is stored as a pointer (4/8 bytes). While `LeftNode` and `LeftResult` are technically optional, each Node contains either a leftNode or a LeftResult, and mutatis mutandis for right. Walking the three for an Input `I` consists of repeatedly evaluating `node->BF(I)`, and then going left or right. If there's a child node, recurse, if not, return the result.

So, this needs to be put on a diet. i've got the full tree available and don't need to worry about modifications, so I'll put it in a single contiguous memory block. My first observation was that we can replace Node with a 16 bit index, since I *generally* have less than 65K nodes. If I store a Depth-First representation, I only need a single bit to indicate whether the left node is present at all, because if it's present then the left node immediately follows its parent node. And that bit is already implicit in the absence of a `Result` value.

I could eliminate the left and right node references entirely by using an [Ahnentafel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahnentafel) but that leaves gaps, and with the size of my BinaryFunction the savings in indices aren't big enough to outweight all those gaps.

So, is there a more compact way of storing these trees? Maybe by using different node types for leave and branch nodes? How would I tell them apart?

I'm targetting embedded systems so we're talking about bits/node here. I'd still like to have a reasonable range for Result (5-8 bits) and the number of nodes (16 bits minimum). I can of course use one or a few sentinel values. The BinaryFunction is probably going to be represented in 48 bits.

[edit]
`BinaryFunction(Input->Boolean)` should have been `UnaryFunction(Input->Boolean)` in the pseudo-code; I should have updated the name when I simplified the example.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted in the second to last paragraph, you can save on space by using different types of `Node`

```
class FullNode {
  BitArray(2) nodeType = 0;
  BinaryFunction BF(Input->Boolean);
  Node LeftNode;
  Result LeftResult;
  Node RightNode;
  Result RightResult;
}

class LeftNode {
  BitArray(2) nodeType = 1;
  BinaryFunction BF(Input->Boolean);
  Node LeftNode;
  Result LeftResult;
}

class RightNode {
  BitArray(2) nodeType = 2;
  BinaryFunction BF(Input->Boolean);
  Node RightNode;
  Result RightResult;
}

class LeafNode {
  BitArray(2) nodeType = 3;
  BinaryFunction BF(Input->Boolean);
}
```

You can determine what node type you're dealing with using two bits, using this information to cast to the appropriate node type

```
Result LeftResult(Node node) {
  if(node.nodeType == 0)
    return (static_cast<FullNode>(node) -> LeftResult)
  else if(node.nodeType == 1)
    return (static_cast<LeftNode>(node) -> LeftResult)
  else
    return NULL
}
```

If you're able to determine the size of the Node, then you only need one bit to distinguish between `LeftNode` and `RightNode`

You can further unwind the nodes in order to eliminate more pointers, e.g.

```
class FullNodeLevel2 {
  BinaryFunction BF(Input->Boolean);
  Node LeftNode;
  Result LeftResult;
  Result LeftRightResult;
  Result LeftLeftResult;
  Node RightNode;
  Result RightResult;
  Result RightRightResult;
  Result RightLeftResult;
}

// Level 2 node with a complete right subtree and only one left branch
class RightRightLeftNode {
  BinaryFunction BF(Input->Boolean);
  Node LeftNode;
  Result LeftResult;
  Node RightNode;
  Result RightResult;
  Result RightRightResult;
  Result RightLeftResult;
}
```

and so on - each node stores two levels of the tree, saving some pointer space at the cost of more complicated traversal code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the node's logical structure would be:

```
struct node
    BinaryFunction (48 bits)
    union Left
        LeftNode (16 bits)
        LeftResult (8 bits)
    union Right
        RightNode (16 bits)
        RightResult (8 bits)
```

So every node has (logically, at least) three fields. There are 4 types of nodes:

1. LeftNode, RightNode
2. LeftNode, RightResult
3. LeftResult, RightNode
4. LeftResult, RightResult

As you say, you can get rid of the `LeftNode` index because if there is a left node it will be immediately after the current node in memory.

Given that, your node becomes:

```
BinaryFunction (48 bits)
NodeType (2 bits)
union
    NodeType1 { RightNode (16 bits) }  // 16 bits
    NodeType2 { RightResult (8 bits) } // 8 bits
    NodeType3 { LeftResult (8 bits), RightNode (16 bits) }  // 24 bits
    NodeType4 { LeftResult (8 bits), RightResult (8 bits) } // 16 bits
```

So your sizes range from 58 to 74 bits per node.

Those two bits are troubling because they cause the structure not to be byte-aligned, meaning that you either eat 6 bits per node or you have to bit-address the nodes array. One way around that would be to remove the `NodeType` field from the node and store them in a separate array at the beginning of your memory block. That way your nodes all fit on byte boundaries, giving you (56, 64, or 72) bits per node. The index itself will require two bits per node, but you can pack four of them per byte, meaning that you'll waste at most 6 bits for the entire tree, and indexing into the nodes array is still easy.

Or, if you could squeeze that `BinaryFunction` into 46 bits, you'd have space for the node type.

### Edit

The above was assuming a maximum memory block size of 64 kilobytes, which was a misunderstanding on my part. If you need to support 64K nodes, then things are a little different.

You could go with two different types of nodes: 16 bits and 24 bits. You'd have to forego the left node optimization, but you could eliminate the two bits per node for the node type. So node types 1 and 3 would be 24 bits, and node types 2 and 4 would be 16 bits. Then, store all the 16-bit nodes at the front of the memory block, and all of the 24-bit nodes after that. You just need a count of the number of 16-bit nodes so you know where the 24-bit nodes start.

Say you have 1,000 16-bit nodes and 1,000 24-bit nodes. So your `BigNodeOffset` is 1,000. Given a node index, you do this:

```
if (nodeIndex > BigNodeOffset)
    nodeOffset = 16*BigNodeOffset + (nodeIndex - BigNodeOffset)*24;
else
    nodeOffset = 16*nodeIndex;
```

You avoid the 2-bits-per-node node type by storing all the type 1 nodes together, all the type 2 nodes together, etc. And you keep four values to say where the first node of each type is stored. The point being that you can determine the type of node based on its position in memory.

You *might* be able to extend this idea to take advantage of the left node optimization in some situations, but doing so becomes pretty complicated and probably isn't worth the effort.

Comment: If the nodes are variable-sized, I can't access them by index but I'd need an offset. In case of fractional-byte sized objects I'd even need an offset in bits. That's 22 bits instead of 16.

Comment: @MSalters: I see your point. For some reason I was thinking that you were working with a block of memory that was no larger than 64K, so the node values were offsets into that buffer. Re-reading your question, I see I misunderstood. I'll have to give this a bit more thought. It might be possible to use this if you can arrange the tree such that no child is more than 65,535 bytes away from its parent. The node pointers then become offsets into the buffer from the current node's position.

Comment: I was hoping that one of the answers would be such a scheme. But one of the challenges will be how you allocate those nodes given the input tree. The Depth First traversal scheme has the benefit of putting one child at a fixed offset of +1, which saves quite a bit of storage.

Answer (score 0):

Google Protobuf stores integers as a [variable sized field](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding). Small integers occupy less space than larger ones.

> Each byte in a varint, except the last byte, has the most significant
>   bit (msb) set – this indicates that there are further bytes to come.
>   The lower 7 bits of each byte are used to store the two's complement
>   representation of the number in groups of 7 bits, least significant
>   group first.

Comment: That doesn't really gain him anything if his trees are large. Granted, numbers 0-127 will be represented as a single byte, but numbers greater than 32767 will require three bytes. If he has more than 32894 (32767+127) nodes, this representation will require more bytes than storing every index as 2 bytes.

Comment: I came up with the same encoding at roughly the same time as Google. The problem is that variable-sized nodes require that I store offsets, not indices. And since I have about ~400KB of data, that's a 19-20 bit number.